# jQuery DOM manipulation from Knockout ViewModel - use bindingHandlers?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I've got a knockout viewModel which looks like this:

```
function myViewModel() {
    this.update = function() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And a bindingHandler which looks like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myBindingHandler = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel) {
        function manipulateDom(element) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I want myViewModel to call manipulateDom whenever the update method is called.

I could do this using a callback set in the bindingHandler:

```
function myViewModel() {
    this.update = function() {
        ...
        this.myBindingHandlerCallback();
    }
    ...
}

ko.bindingHandlers.myBindingHandler = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel) {
        viewModel.myBindingHandlerCallback = manipulateDom.bind(null, element);
    }
}

<div data-bind="myBindingHandler: null"></div>
```

Another idea I had was to use an 'updateCount' observable and subscribing to it in the bindingHandler:

```
function myViewModel() {
    this.updateCount = ko.observable(0);
    this.update = function() {
        ...
        this.updateCount(this.updateCount() + 1);
    }
    ...
}

ko.bindingHandlers.myBindingHandler = {
    update: function(element) {
        manipulateDom(element);
    }
}

<div data-bind="myBindingHandler: updateCount"></div>
```

Both of these solutions feel fragile and messy. What is the 'knockout' way of approaching this sort of problem? Should I just be manipulating the DOM from within the viewModel?

I should add that the manipulateDom function has a lot of logic which isn't applicable in a knockout fashion (measuring window heights, measuring DIV heights etc...)

Thanks!

Comment: did you try using `update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel) { ...` next to the `init` in your custom binding handler?

Comment: That's a much more sensible approach to my second example, but attaching an 'updateCount' property to the viewModel feels a bit messy. Are there any other options? I've updated my original question with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second approach (with counter) is much better, because the ViewModel shouldn't override and change ViewModel's behavior by overriding its properties.

Instead of having counter, if your *update* method does some changes to other observable properties I would create a computed property which will subscribe to the current state of the ViewModel and automatically invoke your DOM manipulation binding if you would pass it as a binding parameter, no need to increment counter or any other flag then.